# Can premature ejaculation be cleaned with a cloth?

Tags: practical-islam, taharah

In the morning I cleaned premature ejaculation with a cloth because it was very small amount then I put my clothes on and did breakfast after breakfast I washed my private parts with water. Is it permissible to do it and if it is not are my clothes impure?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are talking about madhiy that is at its place of excretion on the private part of the body, as the rules differ for other parts of the body or for clothes or land etc.

There is difference among the madhabs on whether it is valid to do *istijmaar* (wiping with a stone or cloth etc.) to remove madhiy. One view is that it is permissible which is based on analogy with wiping after using the toilet:

> #### إذا ذهب أحدكم إلى الغائط، فليذهب معه بثلاثة أحجار يستطيب بهن، فإنها تجزئ عنه
>
> When any of you goes to relieve himself, he should take with him three stones to cleans himself, for they will be enough for him.
>
> <sup>— [Sunan Abi Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/1/40)</sup>

While the other view is that it is not valid because the Prophet ﷺ specifically commanded for it to be washed:

> #### يغسل ذكره ويتوضأ
>
> Wash your organ and perform ablution
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/3/17)</sup>

Washing is also the preferable method, so resorting to it would be better and would also avoid the difference of opinion.

Comment: so my cloths are not najais because of precum

Comment: Any cloth which comes into contact with wet impurity becomes impure.